# Intuitive understanding of behaivor of 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am dealing with the equation:

$$my''+y'+y=0$$

and being asked, what do the different graphs look like for varying values of m between .04 and 1. How can I intuitively figure out what the different graphs are going to look like? Is this some kind of famous function??

Comment: do u know how to solve this?

Comment: ^Mark Watson is correct in proposing this. Intuitively, you should be aware that the solution of the differential equation should have a dependence on 'm'. If you solve the equation, you can vary 'm' and see how the solution is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about this equation in terms of the simple *spring-mass-dashpot* system, for which it is commonly used to model.

[image: spring mass dashpot]

The equation takes the form
 $$mx''+cx'+kx=0$$

Where $x$ is the displacement of the mass, $k$ is the spring constant, and $c$ is the damping coefficient. You have $k=c=1$.

I think that to intuitively understand the graph of $x$ you have to ask yourself: what happens when the mass (i.e. the weight, where $\text weight = mx''$) is small compared to the restorative forces of the spring and damper? And, what happens if the mass gets larger and larger (i.e. $m\to1=c,k$)?